# Parse JSON Results - Is there a more efficient way to do this? (in node-red)

Tags: json, parsing, node-red

I'm looking for a cleaner way to extract data from the JSON results.  Debug results are what I am after.

I was thinking that I would have to extract the JSON file using multiple functions, but the number of results from the http request may be 0-100 or more.  Currently I am doing this with multiple functions, perhaps there is a way to do this with just one?

- I just limited my sample code to bring back the first 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Raw JSON Results]

[image: Desired Results]

```
[
    {
        "id": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 1",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "47821693ff173466",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload"
            },
            {
                "p": "topic",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": false,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "date",
        "x": 360,
        "y": 120,
        "wires": [
            [
                "c7e824482ad27587"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "c7e824482ad27587",
        "type": "http request",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "method": "GET",
        "ret": "txt",
        "paytoqs": "ignore",
        "url": "https://api.pota.app/spot/activator",
        "tls": "",
        "persist": false,
        "proxy": "",
        "authType": "",
        "senderr": false,
        "x": 530,
        "y": 120,
        "wires": [
            [
                "793ce172cd2b36e6"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "793ce172cd2b36e6",
        "type": "json",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "property": "payload",
        "action": "obj",
        "pretty": false,
        "x": 750,
        "y": 120,
        "wires": [
            [
                "be646be526df49b9",
                "fc15ce3272e9c64e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "552a73b1bea7189e",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[0].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[0].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[0].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 120,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a0b7b6ef93ab1f6d",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "payload",
        "targetType": "msg",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 1330,
        "y": 300,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "e2bd2a226ab6107a",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[1].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[1].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[1].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 180,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "664cd814331e3d5b",
        "type": "join",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "mode": "custom",
        "build": "string",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "key": "topic",
        "joiner": "\\n",
        "joinerType": "str",
        "accumulate": false,
        "timeout": "",
        "count": "10",
        "reduceRight": false,
        "reduceExp": "",
        "reduceInit": "",
        "reduceInitType": "",
        "reduceFixup": "",
        "x": 1170,
        "y": 300,
        "wires": [
            [
                "a0b7b6ef93ab1f6d"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "be646be526df49b9",
        "type": "sort",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "order": "ascending",
        "as_num": false,
        "target": "payload",
        "targetType": "msg",
        "msgKey": "locationDesc",
        "msgKeyType": "jsonata",
        "seqKey": "payload",
        "seqKeyType": "msg",
        "x": 750,
        "y": 360,
        "wires": [
            [
                "552a73b1bea7189e",
                "e2bd2a226ab6107a",
                "cb0f561178b1978f",
                "2c7ca67d38934d26",
                "0441dd6d7221b639",
                "2dd3946f0b08f807",
                "cbde257849fb18a5",
                "9277b6d395598bba",
                "851804d09a7d8b5a",
                "2d9c768cb444ab9f"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "cb0f561178b1978f",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[2].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[2].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[2].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2c7ca67d38934d26",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[3].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[3].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[3].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 300,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0441dd6d7221b639",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[4].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[4].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[4].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 360,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2dd3946f0b08f807",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[5].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[5].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[5].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 420,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "cbde257849fb18a5",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[6].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[6].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[6].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 480,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "9277b6d395598bba",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[7].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[7].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[7].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 540,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "851804d09a7d8b5a",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[8].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[8].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[8].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 600,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2d9c768cb444ab9f",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "func": "msg.payload = msg.payload[9].locationDesc + ' - '+ msg.payload[9].mode + ' - '+ msg.payload[9].frequency\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 660,
        "wires": [
            [
                "664cd814331e3d5b"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fc15ce3272e9c64e",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "d2f47fbaea626814",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 510,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": []
    }
]
```

I'm sorry, a little new to posting and not sure if this is the information you need.

Comment: You are going to need to add some more detail about what you mean here. Rather than your flow, it may be better to share a sample of the data.

Comment: sure, data is sourced from the following:  https://api.pota.app/spot/activator

I want to extract the 'Mode', 'Frequency', and 'LocationDesc' from each 'Spot' in the JSON results.  Eventually I feed this into a simple table and/or output to an LED matrix.  I just need to know how to extract each result.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72291299/edit) the question to update with the details and a sample output

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, are you looking the below result

```
array.map(function(x){
    let str = ""
    if(x.locationDesc) str += x.locationDesc + " - "
    if(x.mode) str += x.mode + " - "
    if(x.frequency) str += x.frequency
    return str
})
```